# How to check the sidekiq queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

In a separate tab, I'm running

`bundle exec sidekiq`

and in another tab I'm running:

`SendWithUsInviteeMailerJob.perform_async(invitee.id)`

which kicks off a job that is here:

```
class SendWithUsInviteeMailerJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: :mailer, retry: 2

  def perform(invitee_id)
    SendWithUsInviteeMailer.welcome(invitee_id).deliver
  end
end
```

How do I determine if this job is enqueued in sidekiq? Say this is a test environment. I basically want to see that this job was enqueued for the purposes of a test.

Here's my gemfile:

`...
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'redis'
...`

and in my spec_helper:

```
require 'sidekiq/testing'

  config.before(:each) do
    Sidekiq::Worker.clear_all
  end
end

Sidekiq::Testing.fake!
```

Comment: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing#testing-worker-queueing-fake

Comment: In the terminal tab where I ran `bundle exec sidekiq`, how do I get logging to see what the job was enqueued with? (id number, arguments, etc?)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that. One way is by using `Sidekiq::Web`, a nice graphical interface for viewing scheduled, enqueued, busy, processed, retries, and faild jobs:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring

Another way is by using the terminal. Run `redis-server` and `sidekiq` to start up the services. Now, in the the rails cunsole type `SendWithUsInviteeMailerJob.perform_async` to execute the job, which then will be shown in the terminal pane running sidekiq.

Alternatively, call `Sidekiq::enqued_jobs(queue: :mailer)` in the rails console to get an array of mailer jobs. However, with fast jobs you need to type equally fast in order to catch the job before it has been send to busy jobs (`Sidekiq::busy_jobs`) and been executed.